# Regex for text (string and numbers) between Pipes

Tags: regex

I have this scenario:

Ex1:

```
Valid:
12345678|abcdefghij|aaaaaaaa
Invalid:
12345678|abcdefghijk|aaaaaaaaa
```

Which means that between pipes the maximum length is 8. How can I make in the regex?

I put this

`^(?:[^|]+{0,7}(?:\|[^|]+)?$` but it´s not working

Comment: Actually, you need [`^[^|]{1,8}(?:\|[^|]{1,8})*$`](https://regex101.com/r/xTgbIu/1)

Comment: How can I put this condition [A-Z0-9\(\)\+,-\./:\?\s] between pipes?

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/wohOgB/1

Comment: If my answer is working for you please consider accepting. Or if Tim's is  fine, accept his solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
^.{1,8}(?:\|.{1,8})*$
```

The basic idea is to match between one and eight characters, followed by `|` and another 1 to 8 characters, that term repeated zero or more times.  Explore the demo with any data you want to see how it works.

**Sample data:**

```
123
12345678
abcdefghi                      (no match)
12345678|abcdefgh|aaaaaaaa
12345678|abcdefghijk|aaaaaaaaa (no match)
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Answer (score 1):

When you want to match *delimited* data, you should refrain from using plain unrestricted `.`. You need to match parts between `|`, so you should consider `[^|]` negated character class construct that matches any char but `|`.

Since you need to limit the number of the pattern occurrences of the negated character class, restrict it with a limiting quantifier `{1,8}` that matches 1 to 8 consecutive occurrences of the quantified subpattern.

Use

```
^[^|]{1,8}(?:\|[^|]{1,8})*$
```

See the regex demo.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `[^|]{1,8}` - any 1 to 8 chars other than `|`
- `(?:\|[^|]{1,8})*` - 0 or more consecutive sequences of:

  - `\|` - a literal pipe symbol
  - `[^|]{1,8}` - any 1 to 8 chars other than `|`
- `$` - end of string.

Then, the `[^|]` can be restricted further as per requirements. If you only need to validate a string that has ASCII letters, digits, `(`, `)`, `+`, `,`, `.`, `/`, `:`, `?`, whitespace and `-`, you need to use

```
^[A-Za-z0-9()+,.\/:?\s-]{1,8}(?:\|[A-Za-z0-9()+,.\/:?\s-]{1,8})*$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wohOgB/1).